# Separating development and production parts of django project

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm building a site that relies on the output of a machine learning algorithm. All that is needed for the user-facing part of the site is the output of the algorithm (class labels for a set of items), which can be easily stored and retrieved from the `django` models. The algorithm could be run once a day, and does not rely on user input.

So this part of the site only depends on `django` and related packages.

But developing, tuning, and evaluating the algorithm uses many other python packages such as `scikit-learn`, `pandas`, `numpy`, `matplotlib`, etc. It also requires saving many different sets of class labels.

These dependencies cause some issues when deploying to `heroku`, because `numpy` requires `LAPACK/BLAS.` It also seems like it would be good practice to have as few dependencies as possible in the deployed app.

How can I separate the machine-learning part from the user-facing part, but, still have them integrated enough that the results of the algorithm are easily used?

I thought of creating two separate projects, and then writing to the user-facing database in some way, but that seems like it would lead to maintance problems (managing the dependencies, changes in database schemas etc).

As far as I understand, this problem is a little bit different than using different settings or databases for production and development, because it is more about managing different sets of dependencies.

Comment: Why do you think managing dependencies and changes in the database schema is an issue? You have to deal with them anyway, right?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if your title is precise. Sounds like both the site and the algorithm code will be in production.

Comment: With one project I just have all dependencies in one virtual environment. Having two projects with partially overlapping dependencies seems more complicated. Unless there is a way of having one environment be a subset of the other.

Comment: With one project I just let django handle migrations, with two projects it seems more complicated: in which project do I run migrations, for example?

Comment: Hmm, I can't totally agree on that. You might need a little bit of time sorting out the dependencies for each project, but once you dump them into `requirements.txt` file, you are all set. Also, sounds like your algorithm code doesn't involve in database actions, so I guess it's safe to separate them.

Comment: The algorithm reads items and stores the class labels in the database. As I'm thinking about this, I could decouple the algorithm code more by just having it read and write to a file, then having django read the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84846/discussion-between-ajerneck-and-shang-wang).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move what we discussed to the answer in case people have the same question, my suggestion is:

1. Spend some time define what are the dependencies for your site and for the algorithm code.
2. Dump the dependency list into `requirements.txt` for each project.
3. Deploy them on different environments so the conflicts don't happen.
4. Develop some API endpoints on your site side using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) or [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and let your algorithm code update your model using the API. Use `cron` to run your algorithm code regularly and push the data.

Answer (score 1):

Create a requirements file for each environment, and a base requirements file for those packages shared by all the environments.

```
 $ mkdir requirements
 $ pip freeze > requirements/base.txt
 $ echo "-r base.txt" > requirements/development.txt
 $ echo "-r base.txt" > requirements/production.txt
```

Then adjust your development and production dependencies and install each one in the proper environment

```
#change to your development virtualenv
#$source .virtualenvs/development/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements/development.txt

#change to your production virtualenv
#$source .virtualenvs/production/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements/production.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) as my dependency manager. It lets you define the dev dependencies, rather than having separate requirements.txt files which is extra work.